# accessing data within nested structures

Tags: c++, list, vector, data-structures

I am writing a function that prints out a hash table, the structure for this 
 hash table is 
     `vector< list < Entry > >` and the definition of `Entry` is `struct Entry { string key, desc; unsigned num; };` however I am getting errors when i compile this code...

```
void HT::hTable_print ( )
{
        bool lastempty = false;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hsize; i++){
                list<Entry>& l = hTable[i];
                if(!l.empty()){//if list isnt empty
                        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < l.size();x++){//loop through list
                                if(lastempty){
                                        cout << endl;
                                }


                                Entry e = l.front()+x;
                                cout << setw(4) << x << ":  " << e.key << " - "
                                << setw(5) << e.num << "   -  " << e.desc 
                                << endl;

                        }
                        lastempty = false;
                 }else{
                        lastempty = true;
                }

        }
}
```

I am trying to loop through the vector and allocate each list element to a variable and then loop through that list printing out the necessary information but I will get errors when I call `e.key` `e.num` and `e.desc`. How do i properly call the information for each `Entry` structure?

EDIT: Heres a few of the errors I receive when compiling:

```
hTable.cc:69:24: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Entry> >::value_type {aka Entry}’ and ‘unsigned int’)
     Entry e = l.front()+x;

/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:397:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
hTable.cc:69:25: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘unsigned int’
     Entry e = l.front()+x;
                     ^
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_iterator.h:1198:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
hTable.cc:69:25: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’ and ‘unsigned int’
     Entry e = l.front()+x;
                         ^
```

Comment: Please include the actual text of the error(s).

Comment: `Entry e = l.front() + x;` doesn't do what you think it does. You'd do better to just say `for (auto &e : l) { ... }` rather than accessing each list entry basically by index.

Comment: Please read the [ask] page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how [`std::list::front()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/front/) returns a reference to the first element in list. What you want to do is to take [`std::list::begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/) to have an advancable iterator, [`std::advance()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/) it and then dereference it:

```
list<Entry>::const_iterator iter = l.begin();
advance(iter, x);

const Entry& e = *iter;
```

Or, as per suggestion in the comments, iterate the list via iterators in the first place

```
unsigned int x = 0;
for (const auto& e : l) {//loop through list
   ++x;
   // .... stuff ...
}
```